How to determine the presentation time stamp for H.264 encoder?
I am building a remote streaming application where the application renders a 3D scene and I encode it using VTCompressionSession.
I am struggling to understand the idea of PTS under this setting. Currently, I am using the absolute time difference. However, I am not sure whether this is the correct approach.
How should the time stamp be calculated if I want to stream frames with 30fps?

MPEG codecs use 1000 milliseconds to represent one second. So 1000 / 30 = 33.333 (or is 0.03 seconds). For the PTS, your first frame PTS is time_pts = 0, then next frame onwards you set PTS time as time_pts += 33.333.
